# Сборка pom проекта с maven - в репозитории нет проекта

Tags: maven

Добрый день!

В качестве учебного проекта я выбрал https://github.com/google/error-prone. Мне надо внести в него пару правок и собрать его. Проблема сейчас со сборкой исходников с помощью maven - в локальном репозитории не вижу собранного проекта.

В pom.xml указано, что проект должен быть упакован с помощью pom. Но в этом случае я не понимаю, как подключить мой собранный проект в качестве сторонней библиотеки к другому моему проекту.
Замена pom на jar в pom.xml приводит только к сообщению:

```
'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging.
```

**---Мои действия---**
Я скачал самый свежий релиз на данный момент - https://github.com/google/error-prone/releases/tag/v2.0.15, распаковал, подредактировал pom.xml (чтобы понять, что именно моя сборка лежит в локальном репозитории):

```
    <parent>
      <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
      <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
      <version>7</version>
    </parent>

    <name>Maven parent POM</name>
    <groupId>com.arttest</groupId> <!--заменил google.errorprone на arttest-->
    <artifactId>error_prone_parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.16</version>      <!--заменил 15 на 16-->
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Запускаю mvn install, ожидаю в локальном репозитории (/.m2/repository/com/arttest/error_prone_parent/) увидеть собранный проект, но вижу только три файла:

**/.m2/repository/com/arttest/error_prone_parent/2.0.16/_remote.repositories**:

```
#NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Sat Jan 28 19:58:26 GMT+03:00 2017
error_prone_parent-2.0.16.pom>=
```

**/.m2/repository/com/arttest/error_prone_parent/2.0.16/error_prone_parent-2.0.16.pom** - точная копия pom.xml в корне проекта.

**/.m2/repository/com/arttest/error_prone_parent/maven-metadata-local.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.arttest</groupId>
  <artifactId>error_prone_parent</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <release>2.0.16</release>
    <versions>
      <version>2.0.16</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20170128165826</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Comment: Вам бы следовало пояснить, что значит "собранный проект". У вас скорей всего многомодульный проект. Нужно изучать pom.xml в модулях, чтобы понять, как они собираются. Обычно сборка maven кладется в папку target.

Comment: Да, проект многомодульный. Вроде бы я сумел разобраться с ним.